# Example of a GraphQL query where there are multiple different filter types on a single record type depending where it is located int he query tree?

Tags: graphql

I am [asking ChatGPT](https://chat.openai.com/share/4dfe2e8e-2c1c-4c90-a642-2ae464c78fb6) for help deep diving into GraphQL query possibilities, as I'm toying around with making a JSON variant of GraphQL for learning purposes. One thing I'm perplexed about and have been for quite some time is how you can support query input arguments/parameters on one node but not on another of the same type of node.

Building off that long ChatGPT thread (which you don't need to read for this post), say you have a sort of system like this:

```
const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    author: (parent, args) => {
      // Implement logic to fetch an author by ID
    },
    post: (parent, args) => {
      // Implement logic to fetch a post by ID
    },
  },
  Author: {
    posts: (author) => {
      // Implement logic to fetch all posts by this author
    },
  },
  Post: {
    comments: (post) => {
      // Implement logic to fetch all comments for this post
    },
  },
  Comment: {
    author: (comment) => {
      // Implement logic to fetch the author of this comment
    },
  },
};
```

I am trying to conjure up an image where you have something like this query:

```
query {
  author(id: "1") {
    id
    name
    posts(limit: 10) {
      id
      title
      content
      comments(limit: 10) {
        id
        text
        author {
          id
          name
          posts(createdAtGt: someDate) {
            id
            title
            content
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Or something even more complex.

Basically, we see here that there is `Query.author` and also `Comment.author`, so first part of the question is, why do you need the `Comment.author` scope, why not just use the `Query.author` scope? It's not like we are doing a `Author.posts.comments()` scope, we instead  have a top-level `Post.comments` resolver.

But what if we had a situation where (and I can't find a simple clear example yet) you wanted to filter in one way the posts from `author.posts`, but a completely other way on `comment.author.posts`, _and you didn't want to allow the filtering of posts in one context to be used in the GraphQL query in the other context in the query tree...

Do you ever run into that situation?

Basically I'm wondering why you would choose one direction over the other:

1. Either only allow 1 type of filtering to work across all nodes/records of a specific type.
2. Or 2, specify unique input/filtering functionality on a per-branch level, so one type of record might have 10 different filtering mechanisms based on where it is in the query tree.

If (2) happens at all in more complex production apps, it seems you would have to reimplement a lot of base logic in a lot of different spots in the resolvers, and then customize where it needs be. Basically wondering why you wouldn't just build a resolver that looks more like this (remembering I'm brainstorming about a JSON alternative to GraphQL for learning purposes):

```
{
  author: {
    resolve(parent, args) {
      // Find author by id
    },
    children: {
      posts: {
        resolve(parent) {
          // find posts by author id, and allow `limit` on the posts query, only here.
        },
        children: {
          comments: {
            resolve(parent) {
              // find comments by post id
            },
            children: {
              author: {
                resolve(parent) {
                  // find author by comment author id
                },
                children: {
                  posts: {
                    resolve(parent) {
                      // find posts by author id, but only allow searching for greater than certain date.
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      comments: {
        resolve(parent) {
          // now find comments by author id
        },
        children: {
          author: {
            resolve(parent) {
              // maybe here we have different logic and only return authors with a first name starting with "A".
            },
            children: {
              posts: {
                resolve(parent) {
                  // and another variant here too... it can go on more and more custom cases.
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Does anything like that occur in GraphQL-land? If so, what is a semi-complex example to demonstrate? If not, why not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query:

```
query {
  author(id: "1") {
    id
    name
    posts(limit: 10) {
      id
      title
      content
      comments(limit: 10) {
        id
        text
        author {
          id
          name
          posts(createdAtGt: someDate) {
            id
            title
            content
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Is perfectly reasonable in GraphQL.

1. The selection of `author` by `id` would be controlled in the resolver for the `author` query.

> I'd recommend naming your queries something other than field names just to reduce ambiguity

2. The `posts` *field resolver* for the `Author` type then needs to look at the `args` parameter to find the `limit` and 'createdAtGt`arguments alongside the`parent`argument. In the case of the first`posts`field, the parent will be the`Author`with`id==1`. Later under comments the` Author`parent for the`posts`field resolver will be some other`Author` who commented on the original author's post.
3. The `comments` field resolver under the `Post` type also needs to look at its parent and the `args` parameter to figure out which comments to inclue.
4. The `posts` field resolver shouldn't need to care at what depth it's being called, the parent and the `args` are all it needs.

With this in mind, these other queries would also be valid:

```
query {
  author(id: "1") {
    id
    name
    posts(createdAtGt: someDate) {
      id
      title
      content
      comments(limit: 10) {
        id
        text
        author {
          id
          name
          posts(limit: 10) {
            id
            title
            content
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

query {
  author(id: "1") {
    id
    name
    posts(limit: 10, createdAtGt: someDate) {
      id
      title
      content
      comments(limit: 10) {
        id
        text
        author {
          id
          name
          posts(createdAtGt: someDate, limit: 10) {
            id
            title
            content
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now for the next part of the question:

> But what if we had a situation where (and I can't find a simple clear example yet) you wanted to filter in one way the posts from author.posts, but a completely other way on comment.author.posts, _and you didn't want to allow the filtering of posts in one context to be used in the GraphQL query in the other context in the query tree...

One can attach any data one wants to an object when resolving it. This extra data is passed down through to child resolvers but stripped out when the JSON tree is returned to the client.

So for example in the `comment` resolver`under post when you resolve the`author`you could add an`isCommentAuthor`key to the`author`object and then the`posts`resolver under`Author` could check to see if that key is in the parent and then resolve differently.

Alternatively you could extend the `Author` type into a `CommentAuthor` type (with all the same fields and maybe some other ones) and then have a completely different resolver for `posts` under `CommentAuthor` than you do under `Author`.

Each of those solutions might seem clumsy in some dimension but it's been done before.

There's some inherent tension in your question between what a front-end developer might want from the query and how the back-end developer wants to restrict possible results. Typically the back-end developer should (opinion) provide maximum flexibility while enforcing security rules and providing high performance. It's definitely hard for the back-end developer to anticipate all the ways a query might appear. Having field resolvers act differently depending on their grandparents and great-grandparents adds  complexity. Make sure the benefit is worth that cost.